# How to load image by image using Glide Library?

Tags: android, image, android-glide

I have an application contains a range of image appears by links using glide library, my app takes a long time to load all images so is it possible to load image by image ( one by one ).

```
Glide.with(context)
    .load(imageId.get(position))
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
    .priority(Priority.HIGH)
    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String  model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {   
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            return false;
        }
    })
    .into(holder.CategoryImage);
```

Comment: where did you put this code? is it in the adapter getview?

Comment: @Programming Pirate Yes in `getview()`

Comment: what is the size of your images? Are they large images or just thumbnails

Comment: between 400kb and 1mb

Comment: If you use wrap_content for your image view it will take lot of time. Please have a look at https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1460 that might be of help

Comment: user `override(100,100)` after loading image

Comment: @ProgrammingPirate i use `match_parent` like this 
 `<ImageView
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/cat_imageView" />`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(imageId.get(position))
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .priority(Priority.HIGH)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String  model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {   
                   return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .thumbnail(0.1f) // this will do the trick
        .into(holder.CategoryImage);
```

if it does not work, Try this way,

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(imageId.get(position))
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .priority(Priority.HIGH)
        .override(100,100)
        .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
            @Override
            public boolean onException(Exception e, String  model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {   
                   return false;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                Glide.with(context).load(imageId.get(position))
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .priority(Priority.HIGH)
                    .into(holder.CategoryImage);
                return false;
            }
        })
        .into(holder.CategoryImage);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code :

```
 Glide.with(this)
            .load(sharePref.getUserImage())
            .asBitmap()
            //.centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_account_circle_black_48dp)     // .placeholder(R.drawable.user)
            .into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(user_Image) {
                @Override
                protected void setResource(Bitmap resource) {
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable circularBitmapDrawable =
                            RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), resource);
                    circularBitmapDrawable.setCircular(true);
                    user_Image.setImageDrawable(circularBitmapDrawable);
                }
            });
```